# Can I show glg pictures in Android?

Tags: android

Can I show glg pictures in Android ? What class to use for showing glg pictures if that is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot find evidence of an image format known as "glg", it is unclear if any OS can display such pictures. It certainly does not appear on the [list of supported media formats for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).